# calling API works fine through postman but posting via axios does not work

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, fetch, axios

I am making an react native app, 
I registered a headlessJS which makes an API call. The API works fine through postman but when making an request through app, there's an error
  This is my code in the app for the request

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '13.126.71.152:3000/checkin',
  data: {
      location,
      name: naming
  }
}).then((res) => {
  return res;
}).then((resp) => {
  console.log(resp);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…-5e92abf47ba8:80610)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50- 
9…-5e92abf47ba8:80518)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…-5e92abf47ba8:17922)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…-5e92abf47ba8:17677)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…-5e92abf47ba8:17504)
at 20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…-5e92abf47ba8:17614
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…f-5e92abf47ba8:3478)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…f-5e92abf47ba8:2384)
at 20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…f-5e92abf47ba8:2154
at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (20ecc2c2-cb5e-4e50-9…f-5e92abf47ba8:2346)
```

My server code on node js
My server.js code

```
    var express = require('express');
    app = express();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const path = require('path');
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // Set public folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
       res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
       res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,x-auth");
       res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'x-auth');
       next();
    });

    var routes = require('./api/routes/MetroRoutes'); //importing 
route
    routes(app); //register the route

    app.listen(port);

    app.use(function(req, res) {
      res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'})
    });
    console.log('metro RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

My controller code: `./api/controllers/MetroController`

```
    exports.checkInDetected = function(req,res) {
      console.log(req.body);
      pusher.trigger( 'ieacon-calc', 'checkInDetected', {
      "name": req.body.name,
      "location": req.body.location
      });
      res.json({ message: 'checkInDetected' });

    }

    exports.checkOutDetected = function(req,res) {
      pusher.trigger( 'ieacon-calc', 'checkOutDetected', {
      "name": req.body.name,
      "location": req.body.location
      });
      res.json({ message: 'checkOutDetected' });
    }
```

Here is my routes file: `./api/routes/MetroRoutes`

```
module.exports = function(app) {
      var todoList = require('../controllers/MetroController');

      // todoList Routes
      app.route('/checkin')
        .post(todoList.checkInDetected)

      app.route('/checkout')
        .post(todoList.checkOutDetected);
    };
```

Comment: check URL. It may b because of missing http or https

Comment: I just used the insance IP provided by AWS @Revansiddh

Comment: You need to pass `http://13.126.71.152:3000/checkin` and make sure you already defined `/checkin` post route

Comment: @ArifKhan this url is not accessible by browser as well as I get an 404 status error on App

Comment: that's why I told you, make sure you have defined `/checkin` post route and also you may like to provide `./api/routes/MetroRoutes`  code

Comment: @ArifKhan I added it check it out

Comment: You can not access post request from browser, you need to either access via curl/postman or from your application

Comment: It works in postman but on App it throws an error @ArifKhan

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`app.use(cors());` and it should work.

If creating an API using node, always use cors.
Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to understand about CORS

Comment: Tried that with no success :/